# Error when updating from Joomla 3.3.6 to 3.4.1

Tags: joomla, upgrade, joomla3.0

I am trying to upgrade my Joomla from 3.3.6 to 3.4.1. Whenever I press the update now button I get the following error:

```
0  Cannot open file for writing log
```

I checked that the Path to temp and Path to log direct to the current folders. However, I am still having the same problem.Any help ?

Comment: This is really an administration question not a programming question. You would be better off posting on [joomla.se].

Answer (score 0):

Please check and update your **temp** and **logs** path in the configuration.Also give the writable permission to both **temp** and **logs** folder. hope this information will help.

Comment: I have added writable permission for both folders but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Have you checked the path ?

Comment: Yes I did. Should my configuration.php file be writable as well ? Because it is listed under "Directory permissions" as unwritable.

Comment: No for configuration.php it should have 644 permission and for the root folder it should have 755.

Comment: I have the permissions set as you've mentioned and the logs and tmp folder set as writable and yet I still have the same error thrown. Is there something else I should check ?

Comment: Please cross check you server file path, That must be possible you have entered wrong path. One more thing make all the folders permission to 755 and files to 644.

Answer (score 0):

Go to joomla admin -> System -> System information -> Directory permissions.
See if everything is writable.